# Is there a limitation for document.getElementById("").value?

Tags: php, javascript, buttonclick

I have written a code to read the value from many id's and display the value out when the button is pressed. However, the value cannot been display when it is press. I save the file as php but i need to use javascript for display the value of variable when button is press.Below is part of my code that causes it not working

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>...</title>
CSS code here
    </head>
    <body>  
                $senario_1=3;
                $senario_2=3;
                $senario_3=3;
                $senario_4=3;
        <div id="content">
            <p class="senario_1">Senario 1</p>
            <p class="senario_2">Senario 2</p>
            <p class="senario_3">Senario 3</p>
            <p class="senario_4">Senario 4</p>
            <input id="senario_1" class="senario_1" type="text" value="<?php echo $senario_1 ?>"/>
            <input id="senario_2" class="senario_2" type="text" value="<?php echo $senario_2 ?>"/>
            <input id="senario_3" class="senario_3" type="text" value="<?php echo $senario_3 ?>"/>
            <input id="senario_4" class="senario_4" type="text" value="<?php echo $senario_4 ?>"/>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                },60000);
            </script>
        </div>  
        <div id="menu">
            <button onclick="refresh()" name="refresh" class="refresh">Refresh</button>
            <button onclick="senario_1()" name="senario_1" class="senario_1">Senario 1</button>
            <button onclick="senario_2()" name="senario_2" class="senario_2">Senario 2</button>
            <button onclick="senario_3()" name="senario_3" class="senario_3">Senario 3</button>
            <button onclick="senario_4()" name="senario_4" class="senario_4">Senario 4</button>
            <button onclick="reset()" name="reset" class="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>      
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                function refresh()
                {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=window.location.reload(true);
                }
                function senario_1()
                {
                    document.getElementById("senario_1").value="<?php echo $senario_1 ?>";
                }
                function senario_2()
                {
                    document.getElementById("senario_2").value="<?php echo $senario_2 ?>";
                }
                function senario_3()
                {
                    document.getElementById("senario_3").value="<?php echo $senario_3 ?>";
                }
                function senario_4()
                {
                    document.getElementById("senario_4").value="<?php echo $senario_4 ?>";
                }
                function reset()
                {
                    document.getElementById("senario_1").value="";
                    document.getElementById("senario_2").value="";
                    document.getElementById("senario_3").value="";
                    document.getElementById("senario_4").value="";
                }

        function refresh()
                {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=window.location.reload(true);
                }
                function senario_1()
                {
                    document.getElementById("top_left").value="<?php echo $senario_1 ?>";
                }
                function senario_2()
                {
                    document.getElementById("top_right").value="<?php echo $senario_2 ?>";
                }
                function senario_3()
                {
                    document.getElementById("bottom_left").value="<?php echo $senario_3 ?>";
                }
                function senario_4()
                {
                    document.getElementById("bottom_right").value="<?php echo $senario_4 ?>";
                }
                function reset()
                {
                    document.getElementById("top_left").value="";
                    document.getElementById("top_right").value="";
                    document.getElementById("bottom_left").value="";
                    document.getElementById("bottom_right").value="";
                }</script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Limitations? Well only form fields have a `value` property, and id needs to be unique. What type of elements are you trying to update? (Also, that `refresh()` method isn't doing what you think it does even if the end result _seems_ the same - `.reload` reloads the page, it doesn't return a value.)

Comment: the code looks fine.. something else is wrong and there are no limitations in useing document.getElementById...

Comment: Shouldn't the `<script type='text/javascript'>` use double quotes. I.E. `<script type="text/javascript">`. Not sure if it would cause a problem, but who knows.

Comment: @Jeemusu - Short answer: no. Singles are fine even for xhtml (though lots of people mistakenly believe otherwise).

Comment: can you paste all your code? because I think that the problem relies somewere else..

Comment: Allowable values for NAME and ID tokens are in the relevant specification, in this case I guess [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name): `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`

Comment: Can you give us more info about your problem friend? because It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: so all the values start with 3 right?

Comment: Please note that IE gets name and ID confused, so having one element with an ID that is the same as another element's NAME will seriously confuse it.

Comment: I am testing your code with firefox just to notice..

Comment: what IE are you using? with 8-9 I have no problem

Comment: I think I am adressing the problem because I get Timestamp: 13/8/2012 6:02:04 πμ
Error: TypeError: document.getElementById("top_left") is null
Source File: http://localhost/test.php
Line: 66

Comment: look at my code bellow.. in your example you have defined the methods twise cosing a conflict error

Comment: themhz, the code is working. but why when I use variable to print out then it will causes problem? I need to read the variable value and print out in the box when button is click.

Comment: I using ubuntu 12.04 mozilla firefox to write it

Comment: i think i just paste the whole code for u better

Comment: Ye give thecode so we understand what we are doing here

Comment: uploaded. i edited the one below

Comment: And I think I should Install ubuntu soon. I am sick of my Windows

Comment: haha. ya. i use window for play games only haha

Comment: did you fix the problem?

Comment: yup the problem has fixed. Thank you very much for it themhz and others who comment here also. I also have try all your method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        input.senario_1
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:8%;
            left:30%;
        }
        input.senario_2
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:16%;
            left:30%;
        }
        input.senario_3
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:63%;
            left:30%;
        }
        input.senario_4
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:71%;
            left:30%;
        }
        #content
        {
            float:left;
            width:80%;
        }
        #menu
        {
            float:right;
            width:20%;
        }       
        button.refresh
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:8%;
            width:20%;
        }
        button.senario_1
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:28%;
            width:20%;
        }
        button.senario_2
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:38%;
            width:20%;
        }
        button.senario_3
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:48%;
            width:20%;
        }
        button.senario_4
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:58%;
            width:20%;
        }
        button.reset
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:78%;
            width:20%;
        }
        P.senario_1
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:4%;
            left:30%;
        }
        P.senario_2
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:12%;
            left:30%;
        }
        P.senario_3
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:59%;
            left:30%;
        }
        P.senario_4
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:67%;
            left:30%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <?php
            $filename = 'input.txt';
            $file=fopen($filename,"r") or exit("Unable to open file!");;        
            $data=array();          
    for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
            {
                $getData=fgets($file);
                $data[$i]=$getData;
            }
            $memory=$data[1];
            list($senario_1,$senario_2,$senario_3,$senario_4)=split("\t\t\t",$memory);
            fclose($file);
        ?>
        <div id="content">
    <p class="senario_1">Senario 1</p>
            <p class="senario_2">Senario 2</p>
            <p class="senario_3">Senario 3</p>
            <p class="senario_4">Senario 4</p>
            <input id="senario_1" class="senario_1" type="text" value="<?php echo $senario_1 ?>"/>
            <input id="senario_2" class="senario_2" type="text" value="<?php echo $senario_2 ?>"/>
            <input id="senario_3" class="senario_3" type="text" value="<?php echo $senario_3 ?>"/>
            <input id="senario_4" class="senario_4" type="text" value="<?php echo $senario_4 ?>"/>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                },60000);
            </script>
        </div>  
        <div id="menu">
            <button onclick="refresh()" name="refresh" class="refresh">Refresh</button>
            <button onclick="senario_1()" name="senario_1" class="senario_1">Senario 1</button>
            <button onclick="senario_2()" name="senario_2" class="senario_2">Senario 2</button>
            <button onclick="senario_3()" name="senario_3" class="senario_3">Senario 3</button>
            <button onclick="senario_4()" name="senario_4" class="senario_4">Senario 4</button>
            <button onclick="reset()" name="reset" class="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>      
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                function refresh()
                {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=window.location.reload(true);
                }
                function senario_1()
                {
                    document.getElementById("senario_1").value="1";
                }
                function senario_2()
                {
                    document.getElementById("senario_2").value="2";
                }
                function senario_3()
                {
                    document.getElementById("senario_3").value="3";
                }
                function senario_4()
                {
                    document.getElementById("senario_4").value="4";
                }
                function reset()
                {
                    document.getElementById("senario_1").value="";
                    document.getElementById("senario_2").value="";
                    document.getElementById("senario_3").value="";
                    document.getElementById("senario_4").value="";
                }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The file is look like this
(2lines)
a  b  c  d
1  2  3  4

Comment: can you further explain? I not really understand it. The document.getElementById.value is function properly if only i use for 4 function only. when the senario_4() is used, the value cannot be use. Any solution for it? Thank you for your reply

Comment: when senario_4() is used the value is not set? are you geting any error?

Comment: Thanks for reply again. I have include more detail code for it. The value for senario_4() i have set it but I didnt receive any error. just that all button is disable to function properly after that function is included in the code